# Unzipped archive not available on server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

For reasons I need to zip my build and extract it on my App Service. So in my build I have:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "apps/web/shell/build"
    includeRootFolder: true
    archiveType: "zip"
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/branchName.zip"
    replaceExistingArchive: true
  displayName: "archive feature release"
```

I deploy my app on `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact`:

[image]

And in my release pipeline I extract that archive to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/branchName`:

[image]

Here you see that task in action:

[image]

At the end of the release pipeline I have a script that shows the structure of the build folder:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact
dir
```

[image]

But when I check the folder structure in SCM I don't see the folder:

[image]

Where's the disconnect? Why is everything working as expected but I don't see the actual folder in my App Service?

Comment: Your extraction is happening **on the build server**. Where are you deploying the files to the app service?

Comment: So `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` doesn't always refer to the same value? Since I'm using that to deploy and extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was pretty easy. Extract the archive before doing the deploy.